# JavaFx ListView listener removal when changing items

Tags: listview, javafx, listener

I've been facing a problem recently; I use a ListView of HBox to display text and a CheckBox. I'm using a onMouseClicked listener to select the checkbox when you click on an item of the list. The problem is, when I'm changing the items by clearing and setting the new items, the listener doesn't seams to work anymore. I tried to reset the listener but nothings seams to change. Any ideas of how to fix this ?

in others words, I got this. when i'm clicking on an item of the list, it check the checkbox.

http://hpics.li/597d8db

but, when i'm trying to change the item of the list, it remove the listener. I can't click on the item anymore to check the box. like this.`

http://hpics.li/2b81cc9

i've been adding the listener one time in this function:

```
public void ajouterEcouteur(Interface inter)
{
    inter.list.setOnMouseClicked(new ActionListe());
}

private class ActionListe implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>
{

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        Interface temp = listInterfaces.get(vue.tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        int index = temp.list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if(listHbox.get(index).getChildren().get(0) instanceof CheckBox)
        {
            if(!((CheckBox) listHbox.get(index).getChildren().get(0)).isSelected())
            {
                ((CheckBox) listHbox.get(index).getChildren().get(0)).setSelected(true);
            } else {
                ((CheckBox) listHbox.get(index).getChildren().get(0)).setSelected(false);;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also, i've been trying to add the listener back when i choose an Item into the checkbox like this.

```
if(e.getSource() == interface1.cb)
            {
                if(!interface1.list.getItems().isEmpty())
                {
                    ObservableList<HBox> listhbox = interface1.list.getItems();
                    for (HBox hBox : listhbox) {
                        ObservableList<Node> list = hBox.getChildren();
                        if(list.get(0) instanceof CheckBox && ((CheckBox) list.get(0)).isSelected())
                        {
                            interface1.perm.add(((Text) list.get(1)).getText().trim());

                        }
                    }
                }
                interface1.list.setOnMouseClicked(new ActionListe());

                recherchePermissions();
            }
```

I have no clue on why it doesn't work. If you do, let me know ! 
Thanks !

-Nic

- Sorry for the link, I need reputation for the Images *

Comment: Your question is quite hard to answer as it stands; in particular it would be helpful to see some code. I recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and in particular http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about that, i had litle time, but I tried to explain it the most i can, using code and images